# What's the song during the shogi match between Smith and Gotou in episode 13?

Tags: music, march-comes-in-like-a-lion

Does anyone know the name of the piece that plays in at around 9:20 during episode 13? It's during the shogi match between Smith and Gotou.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 1):

It's "One Blow", track 8 from the [March comes in like a lion Original Soundtrack 3](http://vgmdb.net/album/61951).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgkQ1Bna__o